# Brownish-colored files and folders in Android project (IDEA)?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I use IDEA 11, updated to its latest version. I opened an Eclipse project in IDEA, and the text color of some folders and files are light-brown colored, while others are black as normal.

Look:

1) [image: One]

2) [image: Two]

I tried rebuilding the project, but it did not help. What do the different colors mean?

Comment: Um... I see no brown or black folders in your screenshot. Sorry to be nitpicky, but did you mean "yellow" and "blue"?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Look at the folder names, text color.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These colors represent the file status

> Brown - Unknown - File exists locally, but is not in the repository,
>    and is not scheduled for adding.
>
> Black - up to date

[image]

File Status Highlights - http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/file-status-highlights.html

Refreshing Status - http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/refreshing-status.html

Comment: So, the original developer had a repository (like git) attached to this project??

Comment: Yes, probably. try and click Refresh or Force Refresh. this might make them all to change back to black.